# Using Microsoft Remote Desktop on a Mac via VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I used to be able to access my work computer (a Windows desktop) remotely (on my personal macbook) by logging in to my company's VPN and using the PC's network name (not IP) in Microsoft Remote Desktop.

We have moved buildings and this stopped working.

I have tried using the PC's network name, a static IP and DHCP IP. All result in `Error code: 0x104 PC Can't be found`. I am able to access it using Remote Desktop from other computers connected to the network via ethernet.

What could have gone wrong in this relocation that caused this workflow to stop working? Are there command line tools I could use to inspect my network situation when connected to the VPN?

Comment: You can test the network situation from windows powershell like `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName WorkPC -Port 3389`. From Mac, I think you can use netcat like `nc -z -v -w5 WorkPC 3389`. You will need to check with the company and let them know you moved buildings. There are plenty of reasons you might not be able to connect, especially if the other building was using different subnets/network equipment

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Who moved buildings was the company, so I'm guessing the new network was setup differently somehow? Maybe there's a new firewall setting or so? Definitely VPN/Firewall related since I'm able to connect from within the wired network...